# Pass slider value to bottle route function

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, bottle

I am trying to run a code but one part is not working, where I need to pass the value from a slider. I can see the value in html page but I can not pass it to `inputRange()` where I need to run some commands.

I've tried to isolate only the code which work with slider. Could you please let me know how can I pass the slider value to `val_slide`? Thanks.

Code:

```
from bottle import route, run, template

IP_ADDRESS = '192.168.0.80'
PORT = 8080

@route('/')
def hello():
    return '<b>Test</b>'

@route('/remote')
def remote():
    return '''<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inputRange').on('change mouseup', function(){
    var val_slide ='inputRange';
    $.ajax({
      url:  '/remote/inputRange',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {command:val_slide},
    });
  });
});
</script>
<style></style>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<form>
<div style="text-align:center">
<label for="switch">Test</label>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<input id="inputRange" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="20"  class="slider" name='data'>
<output name="inputRange"/output>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>'''

@route('/remote/inputRange')
def inputRange():
    print val_slide
    # use val_slide value
    return 'inputRange'

try:
    run(host = IP_ADDRESS, port= PORT)
except(KeyboardInterrupt):
    print('Done!')
    quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access query parameters from GET request you should import [`request`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.request) and use [`request.query`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#query-variables) to access to values by name:

```
from bottle import route, request

@route('/remote/inputRange')
def inputRange():
    val_slide = request.query.command
    print(val_slide)
    return val_slide
```

---

I'm not big specialist in JavaScript, but as far as I know, to send actual value (not just static text) you need to replace `val_slide` static text assignment with reading of value:

```
var val_slide = this.value;
```

Comment: I tried to use the new code but still no value was printed. Do I need to use a particular version of application? Thanks

Comment: @Joe, sorry, just noticed that you send GET request from ajax, I've edited my post.

Comment: The last code will return inputRange not the actual number from slider. I tried to use POST with the previews code and the result is the same. Thanks

Comment: @Joe, it prints literally what you send. You have to patch js code to send value from slider.

Comment: @Joe, I've added to answer one line you should patch to receive actual value.

Comment: The last line had fixed the problem. Thanks for all your help.